# check_call and command line arguments on Windows

Tags: python, windows, batch-file, command-line-arguments, scons

My python program is invoking a script on Windows using `check_call`:

```
import subprocess

subprocess.check_call(['my_script.bat', 'foo=bar'])
```

I expect `my_script.bat` to receive a single command line argument (`foo=bar`), but is instead receiving two (`foo` and `bar`). In other words, it seems that the equal sign is being converted to whitespace. Everything works as expected on Linux.

What is the correct way to format this string on Windows such that `my_script` sees a single argument containing the equal sign?

`my_script.bat`:

```
echo %1
```

In my actual application, `my_script.bat` is `scons.bat`.

Comment: Works just fine for me in win7 with python2.7. Are you sure your script that is being called is parsing args properly?

Comment: @jdi: Thanks; I've updated my problem description.

Comment: Not sure why you retagged this as scons? Its specifically a windows batch-file command-line arg issue. Not python or scons.

Comment: @jdi: in the hopes that a scons expert would see the question and recognize the solution. Remove it if you like.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This case tests just fine for me under windows 7, using python2.7

**my_script.py**

```
import sys
print sys.argv
```

**python shell**

```
>>> import subprocess
>>> subprocess.check_call('python', 'my_script.py', 'arg1', 'foo=bar')
['myscript.py', 'arg1', 'foo=bar']
0
```

You may want to verify how your "my_script" is handling the incoming args.

**Update**

Since you have updated your question to reflect that you are specifically working with windows batch files, then here is the solution: http://geoffair.net/ms/batch.htm

> Note: If a semicolon, ';' or an equal sign (=) is used as a command
>   line argument to a batch file, it is treated as a blank space. For
>   example, in the following test.bat batch file -

Equal sign is a special character that will be replaced with whitespace. It needs to be quoted:

```
subprocess.check_call(['my_script.bat', '"foo=bar"'])
```

Comment: Thanks. I think this is just a limitation of Windows batch files. Since I can't edit the actual batch file to strip the quotes, I'll have to find some other workaround.

Comment: @JaredHoberock: Yea its specifically a windows batch issue. In that same article I linked, it suggests its one of those reasons that can make batch files unusable in the first place :-/

Comment: In the Batch file you may use `echo %~1` to show `foo=bar` with no quotes.

Comment: @Aacini: Unfortunately, the OP says he can't edit those batch files